# How to return blocking queue to the right object?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, blockingqueue

Edited hugely ;)

I have a class that starts few almost identical pattern. The way I start them:

```
public class Start{

public static void main(String [] args){

BlockingQueue<Rekord> Queue1;
BlockingQueue<Rekord> Queue2;
BlockingQueue<Rekord> Queue3;

for(int k=0; k < manNum; k++){
    Queue1 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Rekord>(data.addQueue());
    Queue2 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Rekord>(data.minQueue());
    Queue3 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Rekord>(data.multiQueue());

    ManufacturePattern manPat=new ManufacturePattern(Queue1, Queue2, Queue3, k);
}
}
}
```

Inside each `ManufacturePattern` I start `Producer`, `AddingMachine` and `MultiplyingMachine`. They are all started with the same scheme:

```
public class ManufacturePattern{

ManufacturePattern(BlockingQueue addTaskQueue, BlockingQueue minTaskQueue, BlockingQueue multiTaskQueue, int id){
    this.addTaskQueue=addTaskQueue;
    this.minTaskQueue=minTaskQueue;
    this.multiTaskQueue=multiTaskQueue;
    this.id=id;
}
    BlockingQueue<Rekord> queueBP = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(5);
        BlockingQueue<AddingMachine> addMachines = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(2);
        BlockingQueue<MultiplyingMachine> multiplyingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(2);
        BlockingQueue<MultiplyingMachine> waitMultiMachines = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(2);

        service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        service.submit(new Boss(queueBP, id)); //boss creates equations and puts them onto queueBP, here everything works fine


        if(numMMachines>0){
            service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
            for(int k=0; k < numMMachines; k++){
                MultiplyingMachine multi=new MultiplyingMachine(multiplyingQueue,k, id);
                multiMachines.add(multi);
                service.submit(multi);
            }
        }

        if(numAMachines>0){
            service=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
            for(int k=0; k < numAMachines; k++){
                AddingMachine addM= new AddingMachine(k, id);
                addMachines.add(addM);
                service.submit(addM);
            }
        }

        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        for (int i=0; i < numWorkers; i++) {
            service.submit(new Producer(queueBP, addTaskQueue, minTaskQueue, multiTaskQueue, multiplyingQueue, addMachines, multiMachines, i, id));

        }
   }
```

So what the worker is supposed to do look like this

```
public class Producer implements Runnable{

public Producer(...){....}

public void run() {


while(true){
    Rekord record = queueBP.take(); 

    if(record == `+`){
     AddingMachine add = addMachines.take(); //takeAddingMachine, machine solves the problem and sends the result, `AddingMachine` is working ok
     addTaskQueue.put(result) //put the result into other queue
     addMachines.put(add);
     }
    //  cognately for `-` and `*`
}
}
```

The problem is when I create more then one ManufacturePattern. For some reason `BlockingQueues` are put back to wrong manufactures. For example worker from manufacture 0 takes adding machine, and when he puts it back on to the queue, manufacture 1 starts using them. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Your last snippet does not compile

Comment: It is a pseudocode. How could it compile without AddingMachine class in here?

Comment: A pseudo-code should still respect the Java syntax, what is `== +` supposed to mean ? Makes no sense

Comment: You mean that `if` ?

Comment: You could post working example to show the issue.

Comment: As others pointed, your question is not clear. Please take time to form your question in clear manner (with code snippet that you may have) and help us understand your problem.

Comment: All the changes are done